# nodejs socket.io обмен данными с клиентом вне проекта

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, сокет, socket.io

серверная часть:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/live', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('an user connected...');
    socket.on('chat message', function(mes){
        console.log('message: ' + mes);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listeting *: 3000');
});
```

и клиентская часть:

```
<!-- Взял из адрес_сервера:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js -->
<script src="js/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
        $(function(){
            var socket = io.connect('http://адрес_сервера:3000/live', {transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});
            socket.emit('chat message', 'hello');
        });
</script>
```

При этом клиентская часть находится **вне** директории проекта: это обычный веб-сайт в своей public_html.

Проблема: срабатывает только событие `io.on('connection'`, т.е. `console.log('an user connected...')` выводит сообщение, но событие `chat message` не происходит ни в ту ни в другую сторону. При этом если отправить это событие из `test.html`, который лежит в папке проекта, то всё работает.

Так же если написать в клиентской части:

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
  alert(123);
});
```

то ничего не произойдет, алерт не выстрелит.

Обмениваться сообщениями с клиентом вне директории проекта незаконно или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: `var socket = io.connect('http://адрес_сервера:3000/live', {transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false})` Эта строчка - блокирует дальнейшее выполнение скрипта?

Comment: @Дмытрык нет, если написать alert(123); вне конструкции socket.on, то код срабатывает и алерт выстреливает.

Comment: @Лев, URL сервера укажите так `var socket = io.connect('http://адрес_сервера:3000',...`

Comment: @Doigrales Да, заработало! Но ведь у меня указан "обслуживающий" маунт /live, как обмениваться сообщениями именно с ним?

Comment: @Лев, вы хотите, чтобы обмен сообщениями работал только когда клиент попадает на страницу по адресу `/live`?

Comment: @Doigrales По сути мне не нужно попадать на какой-то адрес, я сделал так чтобы идентифицировать и разграничить взаимосвязи. Но изначально я наверно не так понял смысл работы nodejs (перечитать мануал). Мне нужно вот что: есть например 2 серверных скрипта live.js и chat.js, и 2 клиентские страницы (веб-сайты), но только чтобы один клиент общался только с live, другой только с chat, клиенты не должны ловить сообщения друг друга и серверные скрипты не должны видеть сообщения друг друга.

Comment: @Лев, насколько я понял, вы в скрипте создали http сервер, которым по сути не пользуетесь. Вам нужен только `socket.io` в серверной части, где `live.js` создает сервер `io.listen(3000)` и `chat.js` `io.listen(3001)`. А на клиенте уже решаете, кому какой чат доступен.